# SpringDataNeo4j-4: BeforeSaveEvent doesn't invoked on nested entities

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

Have a trouble with nested entities while calling `Neo4jTemplate.save(...)`.

Actually yes, nested entities being persisted as well, but `BeforeSaveEvent` only invoked on parent entity.

In `BeforeSaveEvent`, I populate `uuid` and `timeCreated` fields for all entities.

I don't want to create this value by myself in class constructor.

So, I'm considering the following solutions:

- make it somehow work as I expected (a tough one).
- do not even try persist nested entities and persist all entities in a separate way...
- create `uuid` and `timeCreated` in class constructor
- use external library (most unlikely)

Any advice?

Comment: I've edited your question to [format code elements](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) as code. I fixed a typo (possibly) by changing the second `uui` to `uuid` to match the first `uuid`.

Comment: Thanks! Forgot to format 'code' lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-710 but hasn't been assigned to a specific release yet.

In the meanwhile, perhaps you can use an unmanaged extension that makes use of a [transaction event handler](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/transactions-events.html) to do the job.
If you go this route, the [GraphAware TxDrivenModules](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/runtime) will help.